# Custom menus displaying all pages instead of set pages

Tags: functions, menus

Edit, complete function -

```
function themename_setup() {
    // WordPress Menu Locations
    register_nav_menus(array(
        'primary' => esc_html__( 'Primary', 'themename' ),
        'footer ' => esc_html__( 'Footer', 'themename' ),
    ));
}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', themename_setup' );
```

The primary menu works exactly as expected

I've set up a foot menu location in my `functions.php` file;

```
register_nav_menus(array(
    'primary' => esc_html__( 'Primary', 'themename' ),
    'footer ' => esc_html__( 'Footer', 'themename' ),
));
```

In the admin, I've created a new menu and assigned it to this new location.

However, when I output this menu the menu items retrieved are all of the pages from the admin.

`<?php wp_nav_menu(array('theme_location' => 'footer')); ?>`

I only want the pages that have been assigned to this menu

Comment: Where exactly is that `register_nav_menus` code placed?

Comment: Updated the post

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's pretty easy then... And it works exactly how it should...

You register menu `'footer '` - there's a space at the end (so you have two locations defined `'primary'` and `'footer '`).

And then you use it as `'footer'` - without that space. There is no such location defined anywhere ;)

Comment: Urgh, thanks can't believe I didn't see this, thanks!

Comment: It took me a longer while to notice that :)